# Does Gwibber/UOA auto-follow people on twitter without my permission?

Tags: security, gwibber, twitter

Each day I gain new twitter followers whom I don't want to follow. I have to unfollow them manually. I have checked my twitter authorized apps section. Only two of them have permission. `Gwibber(Ubuntu)` & `Twitter For Android (Official Twitter Client)`.

I asked twitter about their official client. They replied " Our official android client doesn't auto-follow people. Third party apps do that."

When I authorize gwibber the permission page says that it can follow people new people (When I **explicitly** click `Follow` ?).

[image]

But can it do that automatically even without my permission?

I am using Ubunutu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

New Twitter followers are those who follow you and not those whom you follow. It is them who decided to follow you and not the contrary.

If you do not want people following you without your permission, modify your Twitter account's privacy settings. Select the **Protect my tweets** option under **Tweet Privacy**.

Comment: Its already protected. Its not a problem if any one starts following me. But each day i find new followers (as if I have started following them) when I click `Following` tab on web client. But I didn't do that. Its happening without my knowledge. Is gwibber doing it?

Comment: And it doesn't automatically follow who follows me (I am ok with that). It starts following random people & Bots (who doesn't follow me & can't because my tweets are protected).This is annoying.